# How to add user input to a text area?

Tags: html

I have a form that contains an user input (i.e. their name) and on the text area I'd like for it to have something like this:

```
Hello, [their name]!
```

I was thinking of something like this:

```
<form>
    <label for="yname">Your name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="yname" name="yname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
    <textarea variable="yname">
    
        Hello, $variable
    
    </textarea>
```

Comment: Do you want the text in the textarea to appear while writing your name? In this case you should use JavaScript

Comment: No, I'd be satisfied with the text area just showing up with the name there. Because it'd be hidden until the person had submitted their name on the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<form>
  <label for="yname">Your name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="yname" name="yname" onkeyup="update()"><br>
</form>

<textarea variable="yname">
  Hello, 
</textarea>

<script>
  function update() {
    document.querySelector("textarea").value = `Hello, ${yname.value}`
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That works great, thanks! How would I add more inputs, though? 

Edit: nevermid, I figured it out e.e

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use javascript.

So first

1. Select the element to want to read. document.getElementById("yname")
   then use .value to get the value.
2. Select the element where you want to put these values to show to user .. document.getElementById("show") and print the values.. .innerText.
3. Now put the logic inside a function showName() and call this function on onclick event of submit button.

```js
function showName(e){
    var name= document.getElementById("yname").value;
    document.getElementById("show").innerText = "Hello, " +name;       
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form>
       <label for="yname">Your name:</label><br>
       <input type="text" id="yname" name="yname"><br>
       <input type = "button" onclick="showName()" value="submit">
    </form>
    <br> 
    <br>
    <textarea variable="yname" id="show">

     </textarea>
    
    
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it should work. I'm using express on this website and I have no idea where to put the function, do you?

Comment: I am not familiar with express.js sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your textarea to be hidden, add a property `display:none;`

```js
document.getElementById('showName').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var textarea = document.getElementById("show");
    textarea.value = "Hello, " + document.getElementById("yname").value;
    textarea.style.display = "block";
})
```

```html
<form>
       <label for="yname">Your name:</label><br>
       <input type="text" id="yname" name="yname"><br>
       <input type = "button" id="showName" value="submit">
    </form>
    <br> 
    <br>
    <textarea variable="yname" id="show" style="display:none;">

     </textarea>
</form>
```